# How to not remove a blank attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I am generating XML files and using XSLT to remove any blank tags or attributes.

I have recently run it a modification where I need to keep a particular attribute, even if it is blank/null.

Here is the XLST I was using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:if test=". != ''">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates  select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is what my XML section should look like.

```
<patientClinical noClinicalData="">
  <orgFacilityCode>000200</orgFacilityCode>
  <orgPatientId>123456</orgPatientId>
</patientClinical>
```

I wish to keep the "noClinicalData" attribute, regardless of its value.   Currently, if it is null or empty, my XLST is removing it and just leaving

```
<patientClinical>
  <orgFacilityCode>000200</orgFacilityCode>
  <orgPatientId>123456</orgPatientId>
</patientClinical>
```

This is the only attribute I wish to keep.  Elsewhere in my XML, if other attributes are blank/null, I wish for them to be removed.  Is there anyway to modify my XLST step to skip this attribute?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a second condition in your test expression:

```
<xsl:if test=". != '' or name() = 'noClinicalData'">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates  select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:if>
```

`name()` (see [reference](http://www.keller.com/xslt/9/)) function returns current node name and you can use logic operators in expressions ([reference](http://www.keller.com/xslt/8/)).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
 <xsl:if test=". != '' or name()='noClinicalData'">
```

That way, your identity transform is performed on the attribute `noClinicalData`, too.

In context:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:output indent="yes" />
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:if test=". != '' or name()='noClinicalData' ">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates  select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```